# node script with phantomjs lib hangs and no error

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I created this script to take screenshots of domain hp and all associated links in hp from the same domain. The script produces screenshots as expected but after 7-8 URLs the script hangs and I get a timeout error and can't figure out how to fix it...

help?

```
var Phantasma = require('phantasma');
var ph = new Phantasma();
var domains = ['http://www.simpleweb.org'];



for (domain in domains) {
    var dom = domains[domain];

    ph.viewport(1360, 960)
        .open(dom)
        .screenshot('home.png')
        .evaluate(function () {

            var links = [].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('a'), function (link) {
               if(link.hostname === document.location.hostname) {
                   return link
                }

             })
            return links.map(function(link){
               return [link.hostname, link.pathname];
            })

        })
        .reduce(function(links, link){

            var cleanSlashes = link[1].replace(/\//g, '.') // change forward slash to . to be able to save on windows.

                console.log('processing: ' + link[0] + link[1]);

                 return ph
                        .open('http://' + link[0] + link[1])
                        .screenshot(cleanSlashes + '.png')
                        .catch(function (e) {
                            console.log('error in scrapurl', e)
                        })

        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            console.log('error', e);
        })
        .finally(function () {
            console.log('finally!');
            ph.exit();

        });
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not familiar with Phantasma, but in PhantomJS you need to do a ".close" on the page - could this be the problem? Also, you said it happens after 7-8 Urls - does that mean it does not matter what urls, or only on the same urls?